# metastable example of verilog

Tags: asynchronous, verilog

I'm learning metastable and using 2-FF sychronizer .
And I.m trying to figure out it meaning.

but it seem to almost example is about click button and cause it so we need 2-FF sychronizer to solve it.

Is there any other example code of verilog that I can try to test on my own computer?

I think it will more understandable and compare 1-FF and 2-FF by result.

thanks all.

Comment: How will you test it? Using a simulator or emulator?

Comment: Note that metastability can be tricky to find in simulation. It is the reason why it is so hard to catch and so much effort is spent in tools that can check timing correctly.

Comment: yes, if have example, I will simulate and look waveform with vcs and verdi

Answer (score 1):

[Metastability is the result of analog behavior](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/427498/what-is-the-difference-verilog-race-condition-xs-propagation-and-metastability). You cannot simulate metastability problems with a digital event driven simulator. You can only verify that the solution doesn't cause other functional issues. CDC/RDC tools can help statically (i.e. without dynamic simulation) catch design flaws where metastability might arise and make sure they have been properly corrected